# Javascipt code showing on website instead of processing it

Tags: reactjs

I have just installed react and made and opened the folder in Vscode then deleted everything in the src folder and made a javascipt file.Next, I wrote the following code:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
const element= <h1> Hello </h1>;
console.log(element);
```

The problem is instead of processing the code,It was diplayed in the web page and even when I linked an html file to it.The console displayed the error"SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module"

Comment: Is it a module?

Comment: I don't really understand your question I am new to react and modules so  Could you clarify what do tou mean to me?

Comment: The html and javascipt files are in the src folder btw

Comment: I didn't really understand but I got this error:Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
ReactDOM.render(<h1>Hello</h1>, document.getElementById('root'));
const element= <h1>Hello</h1>;
console.log(element);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

ReactDOM.render(<h1>Hello</h1>, document.getElementById('root'));

const element = <h1>Hello</h1>;
console.log(element);
```

This code imports the React and ReactDOM libraries, which are necessary for creating React components. It then uses ReactDOM.render() to render a

## Hello

element to the HTML element with the id 'root'. The last line creates a React element and stores it in the variable 'element', which is then logged to the console.